# ctypes buffer modification

Tags: python, ctypes

I need to call a c library from my python code.  The c library does a lot of image manipulation, so I am passing it image buffers allocated using create_string_buffer.

The problem is that I also need to manipulate and change these buffers.  What is the best way to reach in and twiddle individual values in my buffers?  The buffers are all uint8 buffers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean, something like...:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> x = ctypes.create_string_buffer('howdy!')
>>> x.value
'howdy!'
>>> x[0] = 'C'
>>> x.value
'Cowdy!'
```

...?

Comment: Yes, like that, thanks.  But how can I put an integer value in there (i.e. without having to look up the ascii symbol)?  For example, if I want to set a byte to 0xff, how could I do that?

Comment: Oh wait, I figured it out:
>>> x[0] = "\x43"

I was trying this with "xff", but the printout was throwing me off by actually showing "xff".  It makes more sense when you print it after using a code for a letter.

Comment: @Chris, if you have a small integer in a variable `i`, `chr(i)` gives you the corresponding 1-byte character; the `struct` and `array` modules offer other ways to convert various types to byte strings.

Answer (score 1):

You may find that [Cython](http://www.cython.org/) is a lot nicer then the ctypes module for melding C libraries with Python code.

Comment: Hmm... that does sound useful.  We have a lot of python already written, though, and I don't necessarily want to worry about Cython/Python incompatibilities.  But I could build Python-callable modules with Cython, right?  Might be an option, and might be a little less crazy when it comes to wrapping these functions.

Comment: Cython modules can be imported from Python; the main use of Cython is to make Python modules that wrap C libraries. Typically you would use Cython to do the wrapping, making a native-feeling API and write the main part of your code using the wrapper you wrote.